# Using foreach to fill a 2D array Java

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

So I'm trying to use two foreach loops to iterate through a 2d string array, and set all of the values to a default string. However I must be fudging the foreach syntax. I've tried it two ways and neither work. Should I give up and just use a regular for loop?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test{
String[][] table;
table = new String[11][6];
for(String[] x:table) {
for(String z:x) {
z="asd";}}
}
```

So at this point the problem is that java is just redefining the loop variable and not touching the actual array. So I tried putting this into the 2nd loop instead:

```
table[x][z]="asd";
```

Which didnt work because neither of those point to an int. So I guess my question is:
Is there any way to point java to the index that it is currently on in a foreach loop using the loop variables of the foreach loop itself? Do I use something like getIndex()? Or do I have to just add an int variable to each loop and ++ it to be able to have indexes?

Comment: What is the name of the class? Please put the entire code.

Comment: ok will edit now

Comment: You can't use a foreach lop to write in an array. A foreach loop is used to **get** the values in the array. Use traditional for loops.

Comment: You also can't put arbitrary code directly in a class. It must be in a method or constructor or init block.

Comment: Right, it was in the constructor in the full class. I took it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

foreach returns read-only values, so that is why the first approach will not work.
You can use for instead of foreach.

```
for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    for(int j==0; j<table[i].length; j++) {
        table[i][j]="asd";
    }

}
```

If you want to use foreach, you can keep the indexes separately. I dont see why you would though.

```
int i=0;
int j;
for(String[] x:table) {
    j=0;
    for(String z:x) {
       table[i][j]="asd";
       j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasnt aware foreach had that limitation. This solves the issue.